# How can I programmatically draw a nonlinear writing system with automatic graph relaxation (e.g. in d3.js)?

Tags: javascript, graphics, d3.js, graph

Alex Fink & I have a non-linear written language, [UNLWS](http://s.ai/nlws). Maintaining its grammar document in Google Docs is growing excessively cumbersome, however, because of how much time it takes to load each image — and the images created for embedding in gdocs are not really combinable and exportable in a good way.

UNLWS is primarily composed of a variety of [glyphs](https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=1y15nvR28xPxZMF-pFypB4zaxUAzblj3cG2SjvnGIO44#h.1hjx9gpo5w8q) — which are basically small pieces of vector art with specified binding points (the little blue circles in the glossary) — and which all interconnect with each other at those binding points like a graph (as in trees, not bars) using a variety of methods (mainly simple lines).

Some glyphs have internal structure as well, e.g. variable line or arc length, spline curvature, distance of segments, etc., and some have bindings that aren't drawn with lines (e.g. [articles](https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=1y15nvR28xPxZMF-pFypB4zaxUAzblj3cG2SjvnGIO44#h.dsjl18nb1v8b)).

In general, so long as the glyphs are connected properly and follow some rules about how to connect (e.g. avoid crossings, make smooth or straight lines where possible, relax the graph), the result will be licit.

However, there are also non-graph components, such as cartouches that surround or divide portions of the text, and some cases where certain glyphs must be near each other and placed with specific orientation or distance with respect to each other.

In some cases, we'd also want to hint the graphics package about how to do the layout more aesthetically, e.g. for [poetry](http://s.ai/poetry/st_francis) (note the cartouches in the center and sides) or [stories](http://eaworld.conlang.org/relays/relay19/relay19.php?ring=3&torch=04&ringlish=N&tlit=n&torchlish=y&reverse=n) (note the black-dashed dividing lines of three varieties). For some simpler examples, see our [scratchpad](https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1k1qaEHNRSGNsH0pJvvGtPe6ZSHFUmlpnwyZbcjIK7uQ/edit?pli=1).

Ideally, we would like to be able to compose this programmatically using a reasonable graphics library (possibly d3.js, though I'm open to other suggestions), e.g. being able to:

- define reusable glyphs (with variables)
- let us make custom DSL(s) to specify both the form of glyphs (building up from lower-level vector "phonetics") and how they interact (for syntax)
- tell the package what glyphs to connect at what binding points and how, and have it figure out how to do the necessary graph relaxation etc, with at least a reasonable-looking result
- optionally hint the package on how to do the layout
- add English text in various places with alignment / snapping (there is none in UNLWS itself, but it's useful for documentation)
- export to a standard vector format (eg for printing posters or shirts), and the same to stdout via some command line tool (eg for embedding in LaTeX)

What would be a good way to do this?

I've deliberately phrased this in an open-ended way, as I don't know what an appropriate approach or package set would be (or if JS / D3 is even appropriate in the first place). I would imagine that parts of the problem (e.g. graph relaxation) have been addressed by existing packages, but I'm not at all familiar with them.

(FWIW: Both of us are coders. I've used Ruby very extensively and d3.js a little bit. Alex is a mathematician, and therefore uses LaTeX and Asymptote a lot, but hasn't used JS much. We're not tied to any particular option, including Javascript.)

Comment: I've voted to close this as too broad because an answer that addressed all of your comments would amount to an essay (probably with quite a lot of code) or a pretty complete implementation of what you're looking for. In general, it sounds like D3 would be a good choice, but I don't know if you would be able to do exactly all of what you're looking for easily.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I'm not looking for a comprehensive answer for how to do it, but rather broader suggestions for what packages to use etc. I can code things myself; just looking for broad pointers.

Comment: Ok -- use D3. Too broad?

Answer (score 1):

The Force layout in d3 is probably the best place to start - that's the tool for automatic graph relaxation tool.